# How to invoke all `Mono<E>` at the same time

Tags: java, kotlin, rx-java, reactive-programming

I want to invoke all `Mono` at the same time and get the all values. But the below code are not enough to the both requirements. How to implement this?

```
@Test
fun test1() {
    val m1 = Mono.delay(Duration.ofSeconds(3)).thenReturn("v1").log()
    val m2 = Mono.delay(Duration.ofSeconds(3)).thenReturn("v2").log()

    // waits in 3 seconds but cannot get returned values
    val result = Mono.`when`(m1, m2).block()
    assertNull(result)
}

@Test
fun test2() {
    val m1 = Mono.delay(Duration.ofSeconds(3)).thenReturn("v1").log()
    val m2 = Mono.delay(Duration.ofSeconds(3)).thenReturn("v2").log()

    // can get returned value but requires 6 seconds to process
    val result = Flux.concat(m1, m2).collectList().block()
    assertEquals(listOf("v1", "v2"), result)
}
```

Comment: Sorry, your question is unclear.  What do you mean by "at the same time"?

Comment: I'm just beginning reactive code, so I don't know how to say exactly. I try to explain this as many word as I knew: "`Promese.all` in Javascript", "Invoke in the same tick in a event loop" or "Invoke all without waiting return"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`zip`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#zip-reactor.core.publisher.Mono-reactor.core.publisher.Mono-) function:

```
val result = Mono.zip(m1, m2).block()
```